# How to Read current Time in QTimeEdit in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

How to Read current hour and minute set by user in `QTimeEdit` in Qt, and how to do this in `QDateTime` (read current Day, Month, Year, Minute and Hour)?

Comment: please look at Qt documentation for QTimeEdit and QDateTime. It covers these topics pretty well

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `time()` and `date()` methods:

```
const int hour   = timeEdit->time().hour();
const int minute = timeEdit->time().minute();
const int day    = dateEdit->date().day();
const int month  = dateEdit->date().month();
const int year   = dateEdit->date().year();
```

Comment: Also supports timeEdit->time().second(); ?

Comment: @ChrisP Sure. I haven't mentioned other units in my answer because they weren't present in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

You can read time for `QTimeEdit` as below:

```
 QTimeEdit* timeEdit = new QTimeEdit();  // created the object 

 // write code to initialize QTimeEdit as per your requirement 

 // Put below code wherever you want to read QTimeEdit Data

 QTime enTime = timeEdit->time()    // Read the Current time from QTimeEdit Object
 qDebug() << enTime.toString();     // Printing time in Console
```

I hope this will help you to read current hour and minute setted by user in `QTimeEdit` in Qt